# JSP dynamically change include page

Tags: java, jsp

I have a `<div>` tag:

```
<div id="content">
    <jsp:include page="some.jsp"/>
</div>
```

Also I have a few buttons:

```
<input type="submit" name="btn1" value="Page1">
<input type="submit" name="btn2" value="Page2">
```

I need when I click btn1 some.jsp changes to page1.jsp and to page2.jsp when click btn2.

Answer (score 2):

Use dynamic include,

```
<jsp:include page="<%= myVariable %>" flush="true" />
```

Pd: Take a look a flush http://www.coderanch.com/t/484149/JSP/java/flush-true-jsp-include-tag.

Comment: How do I set  myVariable when btn1 was clicked?

Answer (score 1):

1- Instead of using static include, you can use dynamic include, then you can do something like this:

```
 <jsp:include page="${somePage}" flush="true" />
```

2- Use javascript to change the action of the form depending on the button you click:

```
 <input type="submit" value="Page1" name="btn1" 
  onclick="document.forms[0].action = 'somePage.jsp'; return true;" />
```

Comment: It is almost what I need but when I use 

**onclick="document.forms[0].action = 'somePage.jsp'**

It is replaces the whole page I need to replace only page in <div>

 **<div id="content">
      <jsp:include page="some.jsp" flush="true" />
 </div>**

Answer (score 0):

Im using this solution : My form is :

```html
 <FORM>
  <select name="choix">  
                    <option  value="choix 1">choix 1</option> 
                    <option value="choix 2">choix 2</option>
                    <option value="choix 3">choix 3</option>   
                   
                
        </select>
                
            <input type="submit" />
</FORM>
```

and im using this in the same jsp page to include a page as what i select in that form:

```html
     <% 
     Ch = request.getParameter("choix");
     %>  
    
         <div id="inculde_page">
             <jsp:include page="<%= "layouts/" + Ch + ".jsp" %>" />
         </div>
```